# ERROR ITMS-90023: Missing required icon file

Tags: ios, xcode

So when I try to achieve my project I get this error message:

[image]

My App Icons looks like this:

[image]

Any suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your icons. You didn't provide the one for the iPad Pro which needs to be 167x167 just like what's stated in the error message.

Add the missing iPad Pro icon and your error will be fixed.

Comment: @Downvoter - why? Don't down vote all answers just because you don't like the question.

Comment: @RoduckNickes All the images are automatically "assigned" to the correct icon except for the iPad pro icon. Is this behaviour also according with your icons?